# Correct way to use npm-cache VS Team Services

Tags: npm, continuous-integration, repository, azure-devops

I'm currently using `npm install` to install all packages for an Angular2 project CI project, however this step has started to increase the time it takes build agents to build the project. I would like to get build run times down for our CI pipeline by using the `npm-cache` command, however I keep getting failed attempts at running the command through the build agent.

I have tried using a Command Line step with the following:

[image]

This result in the error `File name doesn't indicate a full path to a executable file`.

I have also tried added an npm step:

[image]

Which results in the following:

> 2017-06-14T13:01:13.2274922Z [command]C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd cache install
>
> 2017-06-14T13:01:19.8609829Z npm ERR! Usage: npm cache add tarball file
>
> 2017-06-14T13:01:19.8630626Z npm ERR! npm cache add folder
>
> 2017-06-14T13:01:19.8630626Z npm ERR! npm cache add tarball url
>
> 2017-06-14T13:01:19.8640981Z npm ERR! npm cache add git url
>
> 2017-06-14T13:01:19.8651863Z npm ERR! npm cache add name@version
>
> 2017-06-14T13:01:19.8661607Z npm ERR! npm cache ls path
>
> 2017-06-14T13:01:19.8672137Z npm ERR! npm cache clean pkg@version

What is the correct way to call `npm cache` from Team Services?

Comment: Are you using your own agent or the hosted agent?

Comment: We're using an on-premises agent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install npm-cache package first, then call npm-cache command via command line task.

1. Add npm task (npm command: install; arguments: npm-cache -g)
2. Add Command Line task (Tool: `C:\\Windows\\ServiceProfiles\\NetworkService\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\npm-cache`; Arguments:`install`; Working folder: `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`)

Node: Previous steps uses the **private build agent** that running as service with **NetworkService** account. You can add `C:\\Windows\\ServiceProfiles\\NetworkService\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm` to system environment variable (restart machine is needed) and call npm-cache command directly.

You also can change build agent account to use your account (by default `C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Roaming\npm` has added to user environment variable), then call **npm-cache** command after install **npm-cache** package with **-g** argument)

On the other hand, host agent won’t cache the packages, so it is useless if you are using hosted agent.

Comment: I really cannot thank you enough, following these steps I managed to get npm-cache working and it's now down to 100 seconds as opposed to 6 minutes - thank you!